# Dropdown menu leaves residue after moving cursor to another menu on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have created a navigation menu which has multiple dropdown options. It's working as intended on all browsers except Safari. On safari it throws a strange issue.

Any dropdown opens as usual on hover but as soon as I try to hover on another menu option, previously opened dropdown doesn't completely go away. It tends to leave some residue behind like a broken code.

This is not so on Chrome or Firefox, but only on Safari.

Safari Screenshot:

[image]

Here is the html used. I have just shown 2 menu options in code for simplicity.

```html
<!----- Menu Code ------->
<div class="navbar navbar-default hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-sm hidden-xs">

<!------ Who We Serve Section  -------> 
            
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" >Who We Serve</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            
               <div class="services-menu">
               <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 menu-padlr0">
                 <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/cpg-services/">CPG Services </a></li>
                 <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/financial-services/">Financial Services</a></li>                                       
               </div>
               </div>
               
              </ul>
            </li><!------/ Who We Serve Section  ------->  

<!------ Solution Section  ------->           
<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">Solutions</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">

           <div class="solution-menu">
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 menu-padlr0">
           <li><a class="mega-menu-link" tabindex="0">Customer analytics</a><div class="menu-bottom-line"></div></li>
           <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/customer-experience/">Customer Experience</a></li>
           <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/customer-retention/">Customer Retention</a></li>
         
           </div>                          
            </div>
          </ul>
</li><!------ Solution Section  ------->       
            
          </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the menu CSS,

```css
<!----- Css Used ------>


.navbar {margin: 0 0px;}
.navbar-default {background-color: #3f393a !important;}
.navbar-nav > li {border-top:0px solid #fff !important;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a { color: #fff !important; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400; text-transform: capitalize; padding: 23px 35px;}
/*.navbar-nav {margin: 0 10%;}*/
.navbar .navbar-nav{ float: none; display: inline-block; }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {color: #fff !important;background-color: transparent !important;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {color: #fff !important;
background-color: transparent !important;}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {display: block !important;height: auto !important;padding-bottom: 0;overflow: visible !important; text-align: center; }
.navbar-collapse {width: auto;border-top: 0;box-shadow: none;}
.nav>li.dropdown.open {position: static;}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu{
    text-align: left;
}
.nav>li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {display: block;border-radius: 0px;width: 100% !important;left: 0;right: 0; opacity: 1;}

.dropdown-menu>li {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.dropdown-menu {border:none !important;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
/*    left: 35%;*/
    left: 50%;
    top: 72%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 30px 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    z-index: 999;
}

ul.dropdown-menu>div>li>a{font-size:15px ; line-height:34px;  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; color:#231f20 !important;  font-weight: 400; text-transform: capitalize;  }
ul.dropdown-menu>div>div>li>a{font-size:15px; line-height:34px;  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; color:#231f20 !important;  font-weight: 400; text-transform: capitalize; }

.navbar-nav > li a.mega-menu-link{ display: block; padding: 0 15px; line-height: 20px; }

.services-menu {position: absolute; width: 280px; border: none; left: 10%; background-color:#fff; padding:20px;}
.services-menu>div{padding:0 !important;}

.menu_text{font-weight:400;font-size:14px; line-height:18px; color:#666; text-transform:capitalize !important; padding-top:-3px !important ; height:35px}
a.mega-menu-link{font-weight:600 !important; text-transform:capitalize !important; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:16px !important; color:#231f20 !important;}
.menu-bottom-line{width:60%; background-color:#b2b2b2; height:1px; margin:10px 15px 5px;}
.nav>li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu .sub-menu a{
    display: block; padding: 0px 15px;
}

/*.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu .sub-menu{ margin-bottom: 10px; }*/

.solution-menu{position: absolute; width: 92%; border: none; left: 4%; right:4%; background-color:#fff; padding:20px;}
.menu-padlr0{padding-right:0px !important; padding-left:0px !important}

.menu-btn{background-color: transparent;border: 1px solid #034ea2;color: #000;text-transform: uppercase; margin-top:15px; font-weight:600}
.menu-btn:hover { background-color: #ffcb08;border: 1px solid #ffcb08;color: #fff !important;}
```

Comment: And the javascript? And also you could put them all (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) in the same snippet. That's what it's for.

Comment: My bad about putting them in separate snippets. Also there is no JS.

Comment: I think there should be. How do you expect the class `open` to be added with no JS? Also based on what you provided, the dropdown menu is not working. It's already activated. You can still edit your question and provide a working snippet showing the actual state of your menu. It will also allow you to see that what you provided doesn't work.